# Как я могу создать UI элемент под спрайтом?

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть Canvas который создает префабы(UI) ,но дело в том что мне нужно иметь один спрайт который всегда должен находиться над ними(префабы всегда создаются после спрайта).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
PopUpCanvas - канвас который создает префабы
Green - объект(спрайт) который должен быть всегда сверху
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Text(Clone) - префаб UI Text

Answer (score 1):

В Канве более нижний по иерархии объект отображается поверх вышерасположенных. Поэтому после каждого добавления нового префаба в канву Вам необходимо Спрайт перемещать по иерархии как последний.

```
public GameObject spritePreloader;  //Допустим, это тот самый спрайт, который нужно размещать поверх всего остального

//Здесь код добавления нового префаба в Канву
//...

//Перемещаем спрайт по иерархии
spritePreloader.transform.SetAsLastSibling();
```

Comment: Проблема в том что я создаю UI Text (префаб) и этим способ не получаться сделать(либо я что-то делаю не так)

Comment: покажите на скриншотах что у Вас там в иерархии

Comment: @Veudd "Green" - что из себя представляет это спрайт? Картинка на весь экран? Если так, то переделайте его из `Sprite` в `Image`, разместите в канве "PopupCanvas" - и уже там меняйте у картинки Image положение в иерархии, как озвучено выше в ответе

Comment: Green - объект который считывает касание игрока с ним(то есть точка победы) и я не уверен что могу сделать его image, но насколько я понял , в любом случае я должен сделать либо Green - image , либо Prefab - sprite.

Comment: Помещайте ваш текст внутрь любого другого ui элемента или даже пустого контейнера и помещайте его в последний Canvas(либо сделайте такой сами). Если вам надо чтобы объект был ниже объекта размещенного в WorldTransform, то необходимо написать скрипт который будет выравнивать объект в координатах экрана относительно точки отображения.